# Error 404 Node Js heroku app

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, socket.io

I am trying to the replicate an example, just change `ng-model` name, and the `url` to communicate the client with the server, but that error show up.

#### Error

```
POST https://nuevohorario.herokuapp.com/enviarAsignatura 404 (Not Found)

Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":"<h1>Not Found</h1>\n<h2></h2>\n<pre></pre>\n","status":404,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"/enviarAsignatura","data":{"data":"calculo"},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":"Not Found"}
```

#### Client -> Front - End

```
.controller('ctrl-asignatura',function($scope,sk,$http){

                        $scope.date= new Date();
                        $scope.data=[];
                        var vector = [];
                        $scope.m=function(){

                            $http.post('/enviar', {data : $scope.asignatura}).then(function(response){
                                console.log(response);
                            })

                        }

                       sk.on('registrar',function(s){
                            alert(s);
                        });
```

#### Back End -> Node Js - Socket.IO

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var misocket = require('../routes/misocket');

/* GET users listing. */
router.post('/enviar', function(req, res, next) {

    console.log(misocket);

    misocket.emit("registrar",req.body);
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(200).json({
        message  : "send message"
    });

});

module.exports = router;
```

#### misocket.js

```
var i =0;
var ioapp;
exports.connection= function(io){

    ioapp=io;

    io.on('connect',function(s){
        console.log("conetado");   
    })

}

exports.io=ioapp;
```

#### index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Your "Back End" code shows the router you setup, but it doesn't show the express app that you load the router to. Is there additional server code you are not displaying here? Can you show the code that you initialize your express app and import the router code above? Documentation on this here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router

Comment: Ok, wait a minute, i dot to edit the question

Comment: @LanceWhatley i add more code, can you check?

Comment: In index.js I don't see where you setup the express app. I would expect to see `var app = express()` or something similar, which would initialize the app, and you would then bind your middleware and/or routes to. Where is this happening?

Comment: This happening in the front, i guess, but a friend recommended this, `var express = require('express');
var app = express();`

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like there is code missing and it's hard to help get your route setup when you're not showing how the express app is initialized.

Comment: @LanceWhatley that is all code i have, i copy an example i ma try to replicate but, now don't show error, socket didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are useing **Router-level middleware**

```
var router = express.Router()
```

Try to load router-level middleware by using the router.use() functions.

```
router.use('/enviarAsignatura', function(req, res, next) {
     //your code here
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, just change then variables name from the original project, and  this happened